# How to get content currently being displayed in browser viewport

Tags: javascript, html, browser, viewport

How can I get an indication of what part of a long document is currently being displayed?

E.g. if my html contains 1,000 lines
   1
   2
   3
...
   999
   1000

and the user is near the middle showing the 500th line then I would like to get "500\n501\n502" or something like that.

Obviously most scenarios would be more complex than this, but my requirement is to find which text is currently being displayed in the browser viewport so I can show a status value appropriate to the current text.

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a value in pixels from the scrollTop property:

document.body.scrollTop = 40;

To know what part of your document that is visible, you could loop through (say) all p-tags until you find one with a negative scrollTop value. The one before that is the one at the top of the window.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of iterating all tags.  I used that as part of the solution but I used the offsetTop attribute so I only needed to process all tags once and store the page offset, then on scroll I iterated all offsets to find which tags were top of the viewport.

Comment: Check the newer elementFromPoint() method. It will return a reference to the element displayed at coordinates, say, (20, 20) of the viewport. This element is visible and near the top of the screen.

Answer (score 6):

If you have jQuery, you can use this function to check if a DOM element is currently shown in the viewport:

```
function isInView(elem) {

    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that idea but in my scenario I am writing for a pda and like to keep the code lean so don't use jQuery, but the comparison algorithm is helpful.

Comment: Not even minified?  I can't see how you can get lean code with a lot of functionality without using a framework.

Answer (score 1):

I've just seen a piece of sample code on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
function isinView(oObject)
{
   var oParent = oObject.offsetParent; 
   var iOffsetTop = oObject.offsetTop;
   var iClientHeight = oParent.clientHeight;
   if (iOffsetTop > iClientHeight) {
     alert("Special Text not in view. Expand Window to put Text in View.");
   }
   else{
      alert("Special Text in View!");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. I will use YUI's API to illustrate my example.  First your text must be in some sort of dom element, whether its a span, div, p or anything, it must be in a element.  Here I will assume list item

```
var viewPortY = YAHOO.util.Dom.getDocumentScrollTop(),
viewPortHeight = YAHOO.util.Dom.getViewportHeight(), i = 0,
// get all the dom elements that contain the text, sorry if this isn't exact, its just a rough example
items = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementBy(null, 'li', document.getElementById('item-container')),
viewedItems = [];
    for (i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++) {
        var y = YAHOO.util.Dom.getY(items[i])
        if (y > viewPortY && y < (viewPortY + viewPortHeight)) {
           viewedItems.push(items[i])
        }
    }
```

So essentially, I get all the dom objects that contain the text your interested in.  I then loop through, and whoever's Y co-ordinate is between the viewports Y and Y + ViewPort Height, I put in an array.

Comment: Thanks for this, it would be great, but I am not using YUI's api.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented what I thought was a more optimal solution for my environment:

I am writing for Android so I can easily interact with a Java class from javascript.  My actual solution involved getting `offsetTop` of all tags I am interested in and passing the offsets to java.

Also registering an onscroll handler that passed `window.pageYOffset` throught to the same Java class. Then the java class can compare `offsetTop` of each tag with `pageYOffset` to see which tag is at the top of the current viewport.