# Get all elements in viewport Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search

I wonder if it is possible (in javascript or jquery but without any plugins) to get all elements (for example table rows tr) in current viewport without looping through each of them? I found a lot of examples how to check if specified element is in current viewport, but what I need is a function returns a list of all elements in current viewport. I need this for virtualization because this table should have an infinite capacity and looping through each row from two millions rows is quite inefficient :)

Is there any reasonable way to do this?

Comment: For something such as a table, you can do a binary search to find it, presuming you don't care about or don't use any elements that are positioned outside their parent or that overlap.

Comment: no, it is not possible unless you loop through elements to check if they are off-screen.

Comment: and you could narrow the loop by calculating current scroll position of the window, something like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658496/how-to-get-content-currently-being-displayed-in-browser-viewport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're not doing anything fancy with positioning, table rows in the viewport can be found with a binary search. For example, for 200000 rows, about 18 lookups are required to locate the first row on the page ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpNM7/6/), warning: slow to load). This can be extended to find the last element as well, or you could just loop through the elements starting from the first until you find one that is no longer visible.

```
var rows = table.children().children();
var start = 0;
var end = rows.length;
var count = 0;

while(start != end) {
    var mid = start + Math.floor((end - start) / 2);
    if($(rows[mid]).offset().top < document.documentElement.scrollTop)
        start = mid + 1;
    else
        end = mid;
}
```

Obviously this does not work well if anything is floated, absolutely positioned, etc. In short: The nodes being searched must be in order such that `rows[N-1].top <= rows[N].top`. For something such as a table, this should be true if no styling is applied and no multi-row cells exist.

Comment: I don't really understand what this jsfiddle code doing... It search for first row visible in viewport I assume? Then why it still suggest that the first row is R0? This should depends on viewport position I guess.

Comment: @AdamMrozek: Perhaps your browser doesn't support `document.documentElement.scrollTop`. It works fine in Firefox. I have updated the fiddle to use jQuery's `scrollTop`, which may work better.

Comment: Ok so now I have an another related question: Is there possible to calculate scroll height for table containing rows of different heights? Maybe I should ask another question instead of comment?

Comment: Not without enumerating every row. The only exception would be if the rows are of different heights but only because you just have a few different types of fixed-height (like one is 100px and another is 150px). Then you could count the different types rather than querying the heights from each DOM element.